# How can I save a video I am streaming with VLC?

Tags: macos, video, download, vlc-media-player, streaming

**Is it possible** to watch a video as it is downloading using VLC using **MacOS**?

- My connection is metered, so I'd like the video to be downloaded locally, but I wish not to wait for it to download completely before I can start watching it.

**An example video** link I like to do this with:

- [Video Link](https://download.ted.com/talks/RobinSteinberg_2018-480p.mp4?apikey=489b859150fc58263f17110eeb44ed5fba4a3b22)

**I have tried** checking "***Streaming/Save***" in the dialogue that opens when I click "***Open Network ... (Command-N)***", but it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found THE answer :D

`youtube-dl -o - address | tee filename.mp4 | mpv --cache -`

This allows you to treat the downloaded part just like a local file (seek, fast-forward, etc). You need to install mpv and youtube-dl though (both installable by Homebrew).